R, data.table and manually defined start of 24 hour intervals
please, give me a hint to solve the following problem:
DT[ , .N, by=date], with date is of class Date and format %F,
will give the number of rows by day.
DT[ , .N, by=format(DateTime, "%F")], with date is of class POSIXct and format %F %T,
will also count from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59.
However,  I would like to have the counts from 07:30:00 to 07:29:59 the next day.
I used the terms R, data.table, date, date change or 24 hour intervals for searching, but I probably do not know the correct terms for this problem.
I found a solution which suggested to subtract 7:30 from the DateTime-Variable to convert (real) 7:30 to (fake) 00:00:00.
Is that the way to go?
What I have tried, is this:
>library(dplyr)

>library(data.table)

>DT<-tibble(DateTime=c("2023-01-01 00:41:00", "2023-01-01 01:54:00", "2023-01-01 02:10:00", "2023-01-02 05:01:00", "2023-01-02 08:38:00", "2023-01-02 09:25:00", "2023-01-02 09:29:00", "2023-01-02 09:30:00", "2023-01-02 09:56:00"),
           Date=c("01.01.2023", "01.01.2023", "01.01.2023", "02.01.2023", "02.01.2023", "02.01.2023", "02.01.2023", "02.01.2023", "02.01.2023"),
           
Time=c("00:41", "01:54", "02:10", "05:01", "08:38", "09:25", "09:29", "09:30", "09:56"))


>setDT(DT)
>DT[, ':='(DateTime=as.POSIXct(DateTime, "%F %T"),
          Date=as.Date(Date, "%d.%m.%Y")
)]



>DT[, .N, by=Date]

 

         Date     N
        <Date> <int>
1: 2023-01-01     3
2: 2023-01-02     6

>DT[, .N, by=Date-7.5*60*6]

          Date     N
        <Date> <int>
1: 2015-08-11     3
2: 2015-08-12     6


>DT[, .N, by=DateTime]

              DateTime     N
                  <POSc> <int>
1: 2023-01-01 00:41:00     1
2: 2023-01-01 01:54:00     1
3: 2023-01-01 02:10:00     1
4: 2023-01-02 05:01:00     1
5: 2023-01-02 08:38:00     1
6: 2023-01-02 09:25:00     1
7: 2023-01-02 09:29:00     1
8: 2023-01-02 09:30:00     1
9: 2023-01-02 09:56:00     1

And
DT[, .N, by=DateTime-7.5*60*60]

gives the same result, as above, only with times substracted by 7.5 hours, off course.

I think you should be subtracting the 7.5 hours from DateTime, and then converting that to a date, since you want to count based on the adjusted date.

You will run into a bug if there are daylight saving time switches. (Even if this unhealthy tradition hopefully dies out one day, past records are still affected.) The way to go is to do a sequence with the defined interval, á la seq(Sys.time(), by='-1 day', len=2)[2], which would give yesterday, same time.
However, what you want here is to cut DateTime at 0730 for each available date: First determine the range of the dates. Next add c(-1, 1) days to get lower and upper bounds and thus the breaks needed. Finally cut at the breaks and count. (Since the format is “POSIXt” format, cut.POSIXt is dispatched, just as with seq.POSIXt in seq above).
> library(data.table)
> (date_range <- as.POSIXct(paste(range(as.Date(DT$DateTime)) + c(-1, 1), '07:30:00')))
[1] "2022-12-31 07:30:00 CET"
[2] "2023-01-03 07:30:00 CET"
> (breaks <- do.call('seq.POSIXt', c(as.list(date_range), by='day')))
[1] "2022-12-31 07:30:00 CET"
[2] "2023-01-01 07:30:00 CET"
[3] "2023-01-02 07:30:00 CET"
[4] "2023-01-03 07:30:00 CET"
> DT[, .N, by=cut(DateTime, breaks)]
                   cut     N
                <fctr> <int>
1: 2022-12-31 07:30:00     3
2: 2023-01-01 07:30:00     1
3: 2023-01-02 07:30:00     5

To see which time gets in which bin, you could add a column.
> DT[, bin := cut(DateTime, breaks)][]
              DateTime                 bin
                <POSc>              <fctr>
1: 2023-01-01 00:41:00 2022-12-31 07:30:00
2: 2023-01-01 01:54:00 2022-12-31 07:30:00
3: 2023-01-01 02:10:00 2022-12-31 07:30:00
4: 2023-01-02 05:01:00 2023-01-01 07:30:00
5: 2023-01-02 08:38:00 2023-01-02 07:30:00
6: 2023-01-02 09:25:00 2023-01-02 07:30:00
7: 2023-01-02 09:29:00 2023-01-02 07:30:00
8: 2023-01-02 09:30:00 2023-01-02 07:30:00
9: 2023-01-02 09:56:00 2023-01-02 07:30:00


Data:
> dput(DT)
structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1672533660, 1672538040, 
1672539000, 1672635660, 1672648680, 1672651500, 1672651740, 1672651800, 
1672653360), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "%F %T")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))


Needed a while to understand it, I have to admit. But now, it seems to me, that this is a very versatile solution! Thank you so much!

@dtw Glad you took the time to understand it! When working with dates and times, the details really matter—it's not just about versatility, but avoiding tricky pitfalls like daylight saving changes.

Check if this solves your problem in your real data:
DT[, .N, .(Date = format(DateTime-7.5*60*60, "%F"))]

         Date     N
       <char> <int>
1: 2022-12-31     3
2: 2023-01-01     1
3: 2023-01-02     5


This will fail on daylight saving time switches, see my answer.

In the first run, this solution worked for me. In my special case, daylight saving time errors will only be of minor importance.
